# Fiddler2 blocking C# GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Trying understand, why my POST request not works, i downloaded Fiddler2. Fiddler catch first GET request, but when i sending POST request

```
using (var streamRequest = request1.GetRequestStream()) //Debugging stops here
            {
                streamRequest.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
```

Fiddler nothing catch, and my app just waiting, no exceptions, no crashes, nothing, just empty console window. But if i close Fiddler, request sending and gets response, but response not what i expected, so i trying to findout, whats wrong in post request, but i cant without Fiddler...

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, but you could try to use Wireshark instead of Fiddler. It's a bit more complex (since it works at a lower level than HTTP), but it also allows you to capture network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to call .Close on a prior call to GetResponseStream?

Comment: Thank you!  I saw the same issue as the OP, that GetRequestStream() was blocking.  For me it was nothing to do with Fiddler.  Simply wasn't closing the response stream.  This confused me for a while, as it was working fine when I ran my web service locally in IISExpress, but failed when I ran it on azure web sites.